# Full installation on SAP Data Hub, stuck at SAP Vora installation phase

Tags: hybris-data-hub, vora

I am in process of installing SAP Data Hub (full installation), I am currently stuck at SAP Vora installation phase with the error attached below.

I am installing Vora from SAP Data Hub runtime package, installing on Kubernetes cluster (minikube) hosted on GCP.

If anyone has any clue kindly let me know.

Error details:

> ```
> error: error validating "STDIN": error validating data: unknown object type 
>   schema.GroupVersionKind{Group:"batch", Version:"v1", Kind:"Job"}; if you choose
>   to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
> Wait until vsolution import job is completed...
> Error from server (NotFound): jobs.batch "vsystem-importer-job" not found
> Wait until vsolution import job is completed...
> Error from server (NotFound): jobs.batch "vsystem-importer-job" not found
> Wait until vsolution import job is completed...
> ```
>
> [image: Error screen shot]

Comment: Can you share your error message in text form?

Comment: added, please chk